# Calculate values to represent bus route attribute

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, route, spatial-join, overlapping-features

I'm working with bus routes and looking for a way to represent some values in this system.

I want each street to be represented by thickness based on value returned in SUM or COUNT. I don't have big issues with Symbology process but some getting those values.

I have two layers:

1. Streets/roads. No overlapping lines. Topology OK. Attribute table with STREET_NAME, ID.
2. Bus lines. One feature per bus line/direction. Attribute table with variables for these lines like number of passengers, name, direction. Some lines, or part of them, are overlapping.

What I did until now in ArcGIS:

1. Spatial Join with this two layers (one to many, match option WITHIN)
2. Dissolve by street’s name+ID. Trying to SUM some fields and COUNT another.

Results:

1. Ok for SUM fields (p. ex. number of passengers)
2. COUNT return 0 when COUNT using LINE_NAME field (text). Solved by create a field (double) and fill with value “1” for each feature. Now COUNT or SUM function returns the number of bus routes over each street.

Any help in this process, alternative or optimized way?

I’m using ArcGIS and QGIS in this project.

Thanks.

UPDATE

Attached some images with results using SUM on Dissolve function. I achieved what I wanted but I'm interested if there some better other option in this process.
I´m not planning to build a Network now. Maybe in the future as I don't know if is possible to represent these infos in a Network Dataset.

Thanks again.

[image: Streets] [image: Bus routes] [image: SUM on bus routes]

Comment: I think this is a question where the inclusion of a picture showing what you are after would make that much clearer to potential answerers.  At the moment I am not able to discern the specific problem that you are hoping we can help you to address.

Comment: @PolyGeo Thanks for your answer. I added some more infos in the post.